# How do I know which inspection condition to disable in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I'm trying to disable some of the less important lint warnings in android studio, but I don't want to browse through the 100s of condition I see in the settings.

Is there a way to get the exact condition I need to disable from the highlighted info below ?

[image]

Comment: IIRC, Alt+Enter -> disable inspection

Comment: does Alt+Enter work on where the cursor hovers, selected text or the active cursor? I get different results every time ... I did get a menu where it showed 'disable', but the yellow background still shows, so I don't know if it kicked in